# Order pending but credit card charged drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

I am using authorize.net gateway and when I have done test runs myself everything is great. But we had our first order today and was only notified when saw authorize.net charge. The credit card charge went through BUT Drupal commerce shows order as PENDING. and no email is sent, what could this be? Is there a final step they are not completing but still after payment? This is strange.

Comment: The order being in pending sounds right, Commerce doesn't assume it's completed because payment's been taken (there may still be fulfilment etc). You can change that workflow in the store rules.  I'm not sure if there's supposed to be an email out of the box, but again it's a rule, probably worth checking which ones you have enabled

Comment: Please only post your support requests in one place next time. I duplicate answered this in the Commerce queue even though our issue submission guidelines point all support requests like this to this site. We're trying to avoid duplicate effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is you need to set the workflow to set the order as completed. Commerce out of the box takes the safe route and assumes nothing about your shopping cart workflow. There is an email that can be configured in Rules for the order confirmation.

The order confirmation email is sent by the rule named `Send an order notification e-mail` that is under the tag `Commerce Checkout` in the Rules UI.

To update the order as completed you will need to create a new rule to set the order as completed based on your business rules. It can be as simple as setting the order as completed upon successful completion of an order.

You can use the event `Completing the checkout process` which will trigger after a successful card charge with Auth.net module or any of the other payment modules, Conditions are none for a simple checkout, actions are `Update the order state`, data selector is `commerce-order` then "Order State" is "Completed".

Here is a visual of the rule:
[image: Generic checkout completion for Drupal Commerce]

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot of sense not sure it worked before in my tests though I set up a rule to send email and it was doing so.